# What statistical method do you suggest for mean frequencies?

Tags: chi-squared-test, frequency

This is the situation: I observed 12 classes (4 elementary, 4 intermediate and 4 advanced) without any intervention or treatment. Each class was taught by a different teacher. Then I counted the number of uses of irony used by each teacher in each class. I came up with these numbers:

```
Elementary level    Intermediate level   Advanced level:
teacher 1: 1        teacher 1: 1         teacher 1: 1
teacher 2: 0        teacher 2: 2         teacher 2: 2
teacher 3: 1        teacher 3: 1         teacher 3: 2
teacher 4: 0        teacher 4: 0         teacher 4: 2
(mean: 0.5)         (mean: 1)            (mean: 1.75)
```

Apparently the mean frequency of irony use has doubled and tripled from elementary level(0.5) intermediate (1) and to advanced level(1.75). But is this increase in the number of irony use statistically significant? How can I test it? I would be really grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: Imagine, for a moment, that these results are "significant": what would that tell you?  Did you select these classes and these teachers in a way that would justify generalizing their behaviors to any other classes or any other teachers?  If not, then what really is the objective of your data collection?

Comment: If you have 12 different teachers, is there any basis on which to claim that the difference isn't just due to different teachers being employed to teach those different levels?

Answer (score 0):

So, you do a hypothesis test. You need more data points, like 20. Use excel to perform a t test, unpooled variances. Look for the (p) value. If it's less than .05 then there is a significant difference between TWO groups of data's respective means, with 95 percent confidence.. Use ANOVA for multiple groups. Use 0 for the value excel asks for called, the hypothesized mean.

With that said, you need way more data.

Comment: Aside from the problem of teacher and class-level being confounded, note that this is count data -- with very low counts. Why is ANOVA suitable?

Comment: 3 different data sets to compare to each other, right? Something like a t test would only compare 2.

Comment: But ANOVA carries some assumptions...; with small counts you have skewed distributions, unequal variances (smaller mean implies smaller variance as you jam up against 0), and the distribution is clearly discrete, in a way that it seems difficult to just ignore. I say again, why is ANOVA suitable? Why would you not use a comparison of means more directly suited to counts?

Comment: I'm learning a lot from you Glen. I clearly don't know enough to have a foot in this. I didn't even think about the data being discrete.

Comment: The skewness and unequal variances will impact both the type I error rate (the actual significance level), and the power though it's difficult for me to say how much without say a simulation study of small counts with similar characteristics. It may be not be very bad because the sample sizes are equal (that offers some robustness to unequal variance at least). The small sample size means that we may have considerable sensitivity of significance level to the distribution and relative efficiency issues (beyond those attributable to the changed $\alpha$) won't go away even at least sample size